# Nhibernate throws error No persister for:

Tags: nhibernate

Mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"  auto-import="true">
    <class name="PlayHibernate.Employee, PlayHibernate" lazy="false">
        <id name="id" access="field">
            <generator class="native"/>  
        </id>  
        <property name="name" access="field" column="name"/>  
        <many-to-one access="field" name="manager" column="manager" cascade="all"/>  
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I tried setting the mapping file as a resource, but that just changes the error message to 
"Unhandled Exception: NHibernate.MappingException: PlayHibernate.Employee.hbm.xml
(5,31): XML validation error: The element 'id' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapp
ing-2.2' cannot contain text. ---> System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationExceptio
n: The element 'id' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2' cannot contain tex
t."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first error *"No persister for..."* was a consequence of not setting mapping file as an embedded resource.

The current error has something to do with your `id` definition. It looks like you have some text within your `<id>` definition. Maybe some unallowed whitespaces? Try to write it as:

```
<id name="id" access="field" column="uid" generator="native" />
```

Also if that doesn't help, try to use some other name than id for a field name. Maybe `Id`.

Comment: The field name shouldn't be a problem. Whitespace? I don't know. I guess that he missed a `<` characters and didn't compile the dll again.

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing out that the error "No persister for" was because of my mapping file not being an embedded resource. Solved the issue I've been having for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio remember change the property: "Compilation action" of your .hbm.xml file to : "Embedded resource"